# parse a key:value style file and get a value

Tags: python

I have a text file which looks like:

```
{

    "content": 
    [
    {
        "id": "myid1",
        "path": "/x/y"
    },
    {
        "id": "myid2",
        "path": "/a/b"
    }
    ]
 }
```

Is there a way to get the value corresponding to "id" when I pass the 
    "path" value to my method? For example when I pass /a/b I should get "myid2" in 
    return. Should I create a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe explain briefly what it is you need to actually do as I get a hunch that there might be an easier way to do what you're trying to do.

If i understand the question correctly, if you wanted to find the id by passing a value such as "/x/y" then why not structure the dictionary as

```
{

    "content": 
    {
        "/x/y": "myid1"
    },
    ...(more of the same)
 }
```

This would give you direct access to the value you want as otherwise you need to iterate through arrays.

Comment: That is correct, I have a file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/764bef476511ff532802d0097e6f8994 I will pass a string that will be same as the path. I will then return a value of the id corresponding to that path

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like JSON, so you can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse the file. Then, just iterate the dictionaries in the `"contents"` list and get the one with the matching `"path"`.

```
import json
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)

    path = "/a/b"
    for d in data["content"]:
        if d["path"] == path:
            print(d["id"])
```

Output:

```
{'content': [{'path': '/x/y', 'id': 'myid1'}, {'path': '/a/b', 'id': 'myid2'}]}
myid2
```